# Facebook Open Graph Feed Not Returning All My Wall Posts From Me

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-wall

When I use the open graph API to get my own facebook news feed (my wall), everything looks right for the most recent 3 months, but prior to that, I no longer see my own posts (but still see posts of other users on my wall).

I'm using a version of this link (with a working access token):

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed??access_token=putvalidaccesstokenhere&limit=100

as documented on this page:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

And I notice that posts from me (i.e. status updates, shared links etc.) no longer show up from early June and prior. Any ideas why?

Comment: you ever figure this out?  i'm still researching the same issue...

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But if you come across the answer, definitely let us know!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook lets you see only latest 5000 records. Everything older than that is unaccessible through the api. Is it possible that you reached this limit in 3 months?

Comment: 5000 wall posts in 3 months? Nope, I'd say maybe 20-25 at best. Plus, it's not that it's cutting off my entire feed. It's just stops showing my personal posts to my own wall, but I'm able to see other people's posts in the JSON that extend well beyond the 3 months.